# How to fetch only the latest ordered items from the list by eliminating duplicate items SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How to write SQL query for fetch only the latest ordered items and remove the duplicated items. here BOOK Ordered on 2 days so fetch only latest ordered recorded.

expected result

[image]

so here two rows removed and pick the latest ordered items . PEN and BOOK ordered two times but only took the latest order.

Comment: What DBMS are you on?

Comment: @PeterClemmensen- Oracle

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and also: Why should I read the description of the tags I add to my question?

Comment: @Luuk is your comment missing a href for the "tags" part?

Comment: @starballm you mean the href to [tag:sql] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is full working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f88908/12):

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
   ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   ITEM_ID NUMBER,
   ORDER_ID NUMBER,
   NAME VARCHAR2(50),
   "Date" DATE
);

INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (101, 205, 301, 'CAP',  to_date('12-12-2022','dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (102, 201, 303, 'BOOK', to_date('01-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (103, 202, 303, 'PEN',  to_date('01-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (104, 201, 304, 'BOOK', to_date('01-05-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (105, 205, 304, 'BAG',  to_date('01-05-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO example_table (ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date") VALUES (106, 202, 305, 'PEN',  to_date('01-07-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));

SELECT ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date"
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_ID, NAME, "Date"
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "RowID"
  FROM example_table
) DS
WHERE "RowID" = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * 
from( select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM_ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) as rn
      from have 
    ) as a
where rn = 1
;
```

Comment: Is this really meant for Oracle?